# Masterpage method returns null when firing a button event in a derived page

Tags: c#, webforms

Basically on the master page I have a method which returns a "campaign" with the params of a unique Id and a user Id. Which works fine until I click a button in a derived page.

The problem is when I click a button in a derived page the method in the master page returns "null". Even when debugging I see the correct params.

EDIT// The Method that returns null:

```
var campaign = campaignRepository.GetCampaignById(convertedCampaignId, user.UserId);
```

Master page code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                string securityToken = "";

                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["SecurityToken"] != null)
                {
                 securityToken = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["SecurityToken"].Value.ToString();
                }

                var user = User.GetLoggedInUser(securityToken);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    var convertedCampaignId = Request.QueryString["cid"];

                    //If the querystring exists process ELSE force 
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(convertedCampaignId))
                    {
                        using (var campaignRepository = new CampaignRepository())
                        {
                            var campaign = campaignRepository.GetCampaignById(convertedCampaignId, user.UserId);

                            //Does the campaign exist from the passed in query string,
                            if (campaign != null)
                            {
                                ccid = "'" + campaign.ConvertedCampaignId + "'";

                                //Build Navigation
                                StringBuilder sbNav = new StringBuilder();
                                string nav = KTO.Common.Reader.ReadFile("/templates/html/side-nav.html");
                                sbNav.AppendLine(nav.Replace("{convertedCampaignId}", campaign.ConvertedCampaignId));

                                ltlNavItems.Text = sbNav.ToString();

                                ltlCampaignName.Text = "Campaign: " + "<strong>" + campaign.Name + "</strong>";

                                //Get campaigns for dropdown
                                IEnumerable<Campaign> campaigns = campaignRepository.GetCampaigns(user.UserId);
                                    StringBuilder sbCampaigns = new StringBuilder();
                                    string strCampaigns =
                                        "<li title='{campaignName}' data-cid='{convertedCampaignId}' class='js-campaign-item'>" +
                                        "<p class='name-message'><a href='/panel/c/{convertedCampaignId}/' class='campaign-lnk'>{campaignName}</a>" +
                                        "</p>" +
                                        "</li>";

                                    foreach (var c in campaigns)
                                    {
                                        sbCampaigns.AppendLine(strCampaigns.Replace("{convertedCampaignId}", c.ConvertedCampaignId)
                                            .Replace("{campaignId}", c.CampaignId.ToString())
                                            .Replace("{campaignName}", c.Name));
                                    }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Response.Redirect("/notifications/404/");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("/notifications/404/");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("/login/");
                }

        }
```

Derived page logic:

```
protected void btnInviteUsers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtEmail.Text.Trim() != "")
            {
                if (txtEmail.Text.Trim().Length < 75)
                {
                    if (Common.Email.IsValidEmail(txtEmail.Text.Trim()) == true)
                    {
                        string securityToken = "";
                        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["SecurityToken"] != null)
                        {
                            securityToken = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["SecurityToken"].Value.ToString();
                        }
                        var user = Business.Entity.User.GetLoggedInUser(securityToken);
                        if (user != null)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                using (var userRepo = new UserRepository())
                                {
                                    var userInSystem = userRepo.UserExists(txtEmail.Text.Trim().RemoveHtml());

                                    if (userInSystem == true)
                                    {
                                        ltlReturnMessage.Text = "Unfortunately we cannot send the request, as the user already exists.";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        //Craft querystring
                                        string encryptedEmail = user.EncryptedEmail;
                                        int uid = user.UserId;

                                        string userInviteHTML = Common.Reader.ReadFile("/templates/emails/user-invite.html");
                                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                        sb.AppendLine(userInviteHTML.Replace("{link}", "http://localhost:52447/_user-invite/?inor-t-em=" + encryptedEmail + "&inor-d=" + uid.ToString()));

                                        Common.Email.SendMail(txtEmail.Text.Trim(), "", "", user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName + " invited you to join x", sb.ToString());

                                        ltlReturnMessage.Text = "Invite sent!";
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                ltlReturnMessage.Text = "Problem sending invite, please try again.";
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ltlReturnMessage.Text = "Are sure that's an email address? Please try again.";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ltlReturnMessage.Text = "Email Address must not exceed 75 characters.";
                }

            }
            else
            {
                ltlReturnMessage.Text = "Email Address required.";
            }
        }
```

Please consider the method does return a "campaign" on any page but just not when the page posts back.

Comment: Which method in the MasterPage returns null?

Comment: @SteveYoung this is the one: "var campaign = campaignRepository.GetCampaignById(convertedCampaignId, user.UserId);"

Comment: What is the value of `user` on the postback after the button click? In the Page_Load `securityToken` will always be `""` but in the button event you are checking a cookie for the token.

Comment: @SteveYoung I did strip out some code...I'll put it back. It does actually search for a cookie. User on postback is not null, nor is the convertedCampaignId null/empty...Which is why I'm finding this very strange.

Comment: Can anyone help me out on this? I'm starting to think there's a bug in my solution. I have never ran into this issue before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After scrutinising every last line, I noticed that my query string was duplicated. When the button click event fired from my derived page it would post back thus running my logic on the master page. I would assume it played havoc with url-rewriting.

[image]

I fixed this by adding

```
frmInviteUser.Action = Request.RawUrl;
```

within the page_load of my derived page, which would force the request of the url and not postback to the master.

This is why I was getting a null on the method, the param passed was duplicated.

Regards,